# InvalidTaskNameError while trying to schedule a task in a GCP App Engine taskqueue

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, task-queue

I am trying to schedule a task in a taskqueue in GCP App engine using googles taskqueue package `"google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue"` but getting the below error

```
API error 5 (taskqueue: INVALID_TASK_NAME)
```

The name of my task is a `string`

```
name:= fmt.Sprintf("%s-trigger-message-%d-%s-%s", env.GetVersion(), userKey.IntID(), profileID, scheduledTime.Format("2006-01-02-15-04"))
```

Can you please help , where i am doing a mistake . Not getting much references online.

Comment: Please add the actual task name that gets used.

Comment: Can you print the name after the formatting and share it with us??

Comment: @Debapriya posted an answer , Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#naming_a_task) , Followings are the rules defined for the valid task name:

1. Maximum length for the task name should be 500 characters.
2. The name can contain both uppercase and lowercase letters.
3. Can contain numbers[0-9].
4. Special symbols like underscores, and hyphens.
5. Task name Pattern should match with expression :  ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,500}$